# Error Deflate And Inflate With zLib

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I'm trying to compile the *[zpipe.c](http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c)* example in my Linux(Ubuntu 8.04) with gcc, but I'm getting some errors, take a look:

```
[ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop] gcc zpipe.c
/tmp/ccczEQxz.o: In function `def':
zpipe.c:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
zpipe.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `deflate'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/tmp/ccczEQxz.o: In function `inf':
zpipe.c:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `inflate'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x44b): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x4c1): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
zpipe.c:(.text+0x4f6): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop]
```

Remember that I've installed zLib-dev correctly, but why i'm getting this errors?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to link it with the zlib library as well. Just add -lz to near end of your command line.

Comment: FYI... you have to place the -lz at the end:  gcc zlib_main.c -lz

Comment: @György Andrasek Нow to do it on the OS Windows