# undefined reference to `inflate'

Tags: c++, static-libraries

Trying to link against a static assimp library which I built with MinGW. Here are the errors I'm getting:

> H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(BlenderLoader.cpp.obj):BlenderLoader.cpp:(.text+0xd91):
>   undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(BlenderLoader.cpp.obj):BlenderLoader.cpp:(.text+0xe06):
>   undefined reference to`inflate'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(BlenderLoader.cpp.obj):BlenderLoader.cpp:(.text+0xf72):
>   undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XGLLoader.cpp.obj):XGLLoader.cpp:(.text+0x76c):
>   undefined reference to`inflateInit2_'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XGLLoader.cpp.obj):XGLLoader.cpp:(.text+0x7ff):
>   undefined reference to `inflate'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XGLLoader.cpp.obj):XGLLoader.cpp:(.text+0x953):
>   undefined reference to`inflateEnd'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0x9ac):
>   undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0xd5c):
>   undefined reference to`inflate'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0xed2):
>   undefined reference to `inflateReset'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0xef8):
>   undefined reference to`inflateSetDictionary'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0xf52):
>   undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0x1b4a):
>   undefined reference to`inflateInit2_'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0x1efa):
>   undefined reference to `inflate'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0x2070):
>   undefined reference to`inflateReset'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0x2096):
>   undefined reference to `inflateSetDictionary'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.obj):XFileParser.cpp:(.text+0x20f0):
>   undefined reference to`inflateEnd'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(unzip.c.obj):unzip.c:(.text+0x1935):
>   undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(unzip.c.obj):unzip.c:(.text+0x19b8):
>   undefined reference to`get_crc_table'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(unzip.c.obj):unzip.c:(.text+0x1ec2):
>   undefined reference to `crc32'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(unzip.c.obj):unzip.c:(.text+0x1f67):
>   undefined reference to`inflate'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl...\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(unzip.c.obj):unzip.c:(.text+0x1fb5):
>   undefined reference to `crc32'
>   H:\ovgl\ovgl\.\..\dependencies\Assimp\lib\libassimp.a(unzip.c.obj):unzip.c:(.text+0x2245):
>   undefined reference to`inflateEnd'

Comment: Did you include all header files?

Comment: Just to make a note, my download of assimp included the source of zlib and  provided an option to build the included version. I got these same errors until I configured the assimp project to build a fresh copy of zlib, and then had to include this in my application.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632201/error-deflate-and-inflate-with-zlib

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Those are functions in the zlib library. Do you have zlib.h and the zlib library (.a or .lib) and the paths set correctly

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now! I didn't have to link to zlib before when I compiled assimp as static for visual c++.

Comment: Is it possible to include the `zlib.lib` file into the `assimp.lib` so that I only need to include the latter in my actual project?

Comment: @DragonLord makes very useful comment.  It's call zlib, but on Linux the convention is to use the prefix 'lib' on libraries.  Therefore, the file should be libz and the linker flag -lz

Comment: I'm having this same issue but on Windows using MinGW make trying to build JLint, and I try to manually set the path to my libz.dll.a or libz.a but I still get these linker errors. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: FYI: figured it out. Turns out JLint's Makefile is not properly formed (for Windows?). It has the -l flag in the middle of the linker command, where it needed to be at the end of the linker command line.

Comment: @MartinBeckett , how did you know it was function in the zlib?