# Using FFMPEG with QT

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, static-libraries

I'm having a problem with linking FFmpeg libraries to Qt 5.10 Projects.
I downloaded the source code from the official website and successfully compiled and installed to my Ubuntu. I used: `./configure --enable-libvpx --disable-x86asm` them: `make && make install`
I'm able to find the installed libraries in `/usr/local/lib` (which are .a libs).

my .pro looks like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil
```

but i get the output:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: 
/usr/loca/lib/libavformat.a(http.o):undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks for the attention!

Note: I would like to static link it to my project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606124/undefined-reference-to-inflate

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Well, i added 'z' when trying to add libraries, indeed help me with zlib erros!
he problem is the after that my compiler said that didn't found the specified libraries. Now i tried to copy all those .a to the compiler in my Qt folder, the program now do recognize then until i call the function av_register_all(); which gives me undefined reference.

Comment: It is a bit hard to debug remotely but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823772/what-is-the-correct-way-to-include-zlib-in-a-qt-project

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna try to look more deep into zlib and qt. I tought that it was more like qt didnt recognizing these libs. I really do appreciate the direction your giving me. Thanks!!

Comment: Wow, i added 'LIBS += /usr/include/zlib.h -lz' to my .pro file and at least compiled the .pro. Now i just need to solve the other error of undefined reference but in relation of those three added libs Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, I used FFMPEG with Qt but never referred directly to it. I used OpenCV compiled with -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON