# Undefined reference to 'inflateInit2_'

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, zlib, undefined-reference

I'm using Code Blocks IDE and I want to install Tiled Map Editor for SFML. So, I downloaded the source and imported it to my project. Unfortunately, the build finished with an error due to missing zlib library. I downloaded it and built again. This time I received an error that reads:

```
undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'|
undefined reference to `inflateEnd'|
undefined reference to `inflateEnd'|
```

On the Internet I found the advice to join the linker command `-lz`, but the compiler refuses throwing the error: *cannot find -lz*. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You need to put `zlib` somewhere your compiler can find it. On Linux, that means `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` (normally `make install` would handle this), and on Windows there is no standard way, but you either point your compiler to the DLL, or put the DLL inside your compiler's `lib` folder (`mingw` doesn't search the `PATH` on windows last time I checked). What's your OS?

Comment: @add I solved the problem put the DLL inside my compiler. Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632201/error-deflate-and-inflate-with-zlib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option `-L<path>` to tell the linker where to find `libz.so.x.y.z`.

For your reference: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Answer (score 4):

you can see where your zlib is installed like this :

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p| grep libz.so
```

it should find one or more entries if installed, otherwise it will return blank line

Comment: This would suite as comment, but does not answer the question.

Comment: Yes so it seems