# ImportError: /home/yousefi/hemelb-dev/Tools/setuptool/HemeLbSetupTool/Model/_Generation.so: undefined symbol: deflateInit_

Tags: python, c++, importerror, undefined-symbol

I compiled a mixed Python and C++ program in our cluster successfully which previously I have compiled that in my local machine successfully and it runs without any error in my local machine. But in our cluster, when I tried to run that program I received this strange error which honestly I would say I don't have any clue about it:

> ImportError: /home/yousefi/hemelb-dev/Tools/setuptool/HemeLbSetupTool/Model/*Generation.so: undefined symbol: deflateInit*

I want to know anyone have any idea about that error? I should say again the program compiled without any error successfully in our cluster but this error occurred during running. I appreciate any idea or help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632201/error-deflate-and-inflate-with-zlib

Comment: Also I would say that I know that symbol is related to `zlib` and we have `zlib` in our cluster and also I linked `zlib` with `export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib` to `gcc` and also during compilation I don't have any error related to `zlib`.